# How to handle And Where and Or Where conditions in Lumen?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, lumen

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE 
gender = "$gender" AND country = "$country" 
AND ((city = "$city" AND status = "1") 
OR (status IN(2,3)))";
```

How can I write above query in Lumen ?

What I have tried so far is :

```
$users = User::where('country', '=', $country)
             ->where('gender', '=', $gender)
             ->where(function ($users) {
                    $users->where('city', '=', '$city')
                          ->where('status', '=', "1");
             })
             ->whereIn('status', [2, 3])
             ->first();
```

But this query doesn't returns the expected result.

Any idea what is the fault in my query?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code.

```
$users = User::where('country', '=', $country)
    ->where('gender', '=', $gender)
    ->where(function ($query) use ($city) {
        $query->where(function($query) use ($city) {
            $query->where('city', '=', '$city')
                  ->where('status', '=', "1");
        })->orWhereIn('status', [2, 3]);
    })->first();
```